# Get data from put request Yii2

Tags: php, rest, yii2, httprequest

I do rest API. To update data using a PUT request

http://train-basic/stations/21?name=tt

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsZsQ.jpg]

Try get data:

```
$request = Yii::$app->request;
$request = $request->post();

$name = $request["name"];
dump($name);
```

As a result, I get null. How to fix it?

Comment: Include all necessary information into the question rather than providing links. Further more local URLs cannot be accessed from the web. Please read [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: `$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");` or you can use `$params = Yii::$app->request->bodyParams;`

Answer (score 1):

To get data sent in request body by `PUT` or `PATCH` request, you should use [`getBodyParam()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#getBodyParam()-detail) or [`getBodyParams()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#getBodyParams()-detail)

> ```
> $request = Yii::$app->request;
>
> // returns all parameters
> $params = $request->getBodyParams();
>
> // returns the parameter "id"
> $param = $request->getBodyParam('id');
> ```
>
> <sub>https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-requests#request-parameters</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Data from PUT download like POST

```
$request = Yii::$app->request;
$id = $request->get('id');
$name = $request->get('name');
$days = $request->get('days');
```

Comment: You're sending request in a wrong way if this works (data is sent using GET params instead for request body).